# What are the next step after compiling PYBIND11_MODULE in C++ file

Tags: python, c++, c, build, pybind11

I was trying to use PYbind 11 to wrap the following small C++ test programme into a Python module, so I can call the test C++ function from python files.
My problem is : while the C++ file compiled successfully, I have no clue as to what steps to take next to import the newly created module file in python.
I tried to run "from example import add" in a test Python file in Spyder but received error message saying there is no module named example.
I'm using Windows10 (x64bit), Python3.7 and Visual studio 2017 community.
Can some one please help? Thank you very  much!

```
#include
//#include <Aspose.Cells.h>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

void print(const char*);

int add(int i, int j) {
return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin"; // optional module docstring

m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}

int main()
{
const char *x = "C Plus plus is wonderful.";

char *z;
char b = 'z';
z = &b;

int num = 10;
int* a = 0;

print(x);
}

void print(const char* z)
{

std::cout << "pointer z is" << z << "\n";

std::cin.get();
}
```

UPDATE: I followed Stuart's suggestion below when building my test c++ programme. I made two attempts: at the first attempt, I changed Target Extension to ".pyd"; whereas at the second attempt, I kept Target Extension as "dll".

In both attempts, I received the same error message from Visual Studio, which seem to suggest that the DLL file being built can not be started (as shown in the screenshot that immediately follows)
[Error Messages for Starting DLL Programme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/en361.png)
However, the actual building of dll file seemed successful, as I can see one dll file and one Python Extension Module file, with filenames and path listed as follows:
C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.dll
and
C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5

The Visual Studio output message upon building is pasted at the end.

My problem is: I created a Test.py file in the same directory (C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug)
and tried to run it in Spyder after including just one line command "import example ". Sypder returned a error message saying " No MODULE Named Example".

Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot!

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication5, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>LINK : C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.dll not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
1>   Creating library C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.lib and object C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.exp
1>ConsoleApplication5.vcxproj -> C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication5.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

UPDATE2: I followed every details of Stuart's instructions in his Update2.
I got example.pyd (as shown in the following screenshot)
[image: pyd files successfully generated]
However, I got error message when running in Spyder, as follows:
(Sorry I only managed to copy the second half of Spyder output message as its very hard to do text selection in Spyder console)

```
File "C:\Users\rmili\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rmili/source/repos/ConsoleApplication5/x64/Debug/Test.py", line 9
    d = "C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug"
       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I changed backward slash "" to  forward slash"/" in the value that's being assigned to "d", and got the following error again:

```
File "C:\Users\rmili\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/rmili/source/repos/ConsoleApplication5/x64/Debug/Test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import example

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'example'
```

UPDATE3:
As shown in the following screenshot, example module can not be found in Windows command line prompt.
[[Unable to find example module in Windowscommand line prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihB3f.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihB3f.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the compiled output file is named `example.pyd` (or has a symlink of that name pointing to it), and try running python from the same directory.

---

**Update: How to build a `.pyd` in Visual Studio**

On Windows, compiled Python modules are simply DLL files, but they have a `.pyd` file extension.  You mentioned that your C++ file compiles successfully.  Did you compile it as an executable (`.exe`), or as a `.dll`? You should compile it as a DLL, but change the file extension to `.pyd`.

The Visual Studio documentation [explains how to change your project to create a DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dll-build-a-dll?view=vs-2019).  Here's what it says:

> 1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box. For details, see [Set C++ compiler and build properties in Visual Studio.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/working-with-project-properties?view=vs-2019)
> 2. Click the Configuration Properties folder.
> 3. Click the General property page.
> 4. Modify the Configuration Type property.

Also, on that same settings page, you can find an option to change the `Target Extension` property.  Change it to `.pyd`.  (Or simply rename the file yourself after it is built.)

---

**Update 2**

I think you need to change three settings:

- `Target Name`

  - Change to `example`
- `Target Extension`

  - Change to `.pyd`
- `Configuration Type`

  - Change to `Dynamic Library (.dll)`

Also, I recommend deleting (or commenting out) everything from `example.cpp` except for the code shown below.  (I don't know if the presence of a `main()` function may cause problems, so just remove it.)

After that, building your project should produce the following file:

`C:\Users\rmili\source\repos\ConsoleApplication5\x64\Debug\example.pyd`

Than, from the Spyder console, try this:

```
import os

d = "C:\\Users\\rmili\\source\\repos\\ConsoleApplication5\\x64\\Debug"
os.chdir(d)

import example
example.add(1,2)
```

---

I don't have a Windows machine to test with.  But in case it's useful, here's how I compiled your example on my Mac.  (On Mac and Linux, they use the extension `.so` instead of `.pyd`.)

```cpp
// example.cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int add(int i, int j) {
    return i + j;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.doc() = "pybind11 example plugin";

    m.def("add", &add, "A function which adds two numbers");
}
```

```sh
$ # Compile
$ clang++ -I${CONDA_PREFIX}/include -I${CONDA_PREFIX}/include/python3.7m -undefined dynamic_lookup -shared -o example.so example.cpp

$ # Test
$ python -c "import example; print(example.add(10,20))"
30
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not sure how to make sure an output file is generated in a certain extension such as pyd. Does it require installation of some other libraries such as setuptools, or Cmake ? Thanks.

Comment: I have added some explanation of how to do it in a Visual Studio project.  Please see above.

Comment: Hi Stuart, I tried by following your instructions. I think I got the Python Extension Module file, but sadly I still couldn't get my test.py file to import it when I tried to run it in Spyder. I described the details of the story in the update to my initial post. Can you have a look? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please see Update 2, above.

Comment: Hi Stuart thank you for your reply. Ive tried out your instructions in update2 but got a different errors,  and it was from Spyder this time. I've described it in my Update2 too. Can you take  a look thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Hillary, sorry about the mistake in the directory path.  I don't know why your python interpreter still can't find the `example` module.  I wonder if it works from an ordinary Python interpreter.  If you launch `C:\Users\rmili\Anaconda3\python` (or maybe `C:\Users\rmili\Anaconda3\Scripts\python`) from the command line, does `import example` work?  (Be sure to put `example.pyd` in your starting directory if necessary.)

Comment: I think everything you've done ought to work, assuming you built the `example.pyd` correctly (using the correct header include paths, etc.).  For instance, this tutorial doesn't indicate anything else required: https://kezunlin.me/post/8b9c051d  (That tutorial uses `cmake`, but you can skip that step since you've created the VS project yourself. But if you aren't sure if you did that correctly, you may want to try following the steps in that tutorial exactly.)

Comment: thank you for sharing,  let me try both the command way and the tutorial way. by the way, how to determine if pyd was built successfully? I saw it in my folder,  as shown in my screenshot in update2,does it mean the build was ok?

Comment: hi Stuart, I can't get it to work in Windows command prompt either, as shown in my Update3 above. though I'm not sure if it's because I didn't take care of ensuring example.pyd is in starting directory, as I don't know how to achieve that.

Comment: I meant just move example.pyd to whichever directory your interpreter starts in. Use “os.getcwd()” to see where you are, then use Windows explorer to move example.pyd to that folder.

Comment: If that doesn’t work, then maybe you should try the cmake-based tutorial linked above.

Comment: Hi, I was reading the CMake tutorial, and I noticed sth different: the tutorial generated examplelib.cp35-win_amd64.pyd, whereas in my case, I only got a pyd file, where the extension doesn't contain "cp35-win_amd64", do you think this could be the cause?

Comment: Good idea. On Mac and linux, that's unnecessary.  But I am less familiar with Windows.  Perhaps you should rename the file and see if that helps.

Comment: hi , I've done a little bit of research and found this (https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html and https://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll):  To be importable, the shared library must be available on PYTHONPATH, and must be named after the module name, with an appropriate extension. 
The initialization function has the signature:                                           
PyObject* PyInit_modulename(void)  I think it might help to create a function called " PyInit_example" in C++ file.

Comment: The `PYBIND11_MODULE` macro implements that function for you. There's no need to write it yourself.

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that there is still a problem with how your project file is configured.  Is it really compiling the right cpp file? For example, in the code you posted  above, there is a mistake on the first line (`#include` without a filename).  That code should not compile successfully. Why is your project building anyway? Did you accidentally make a mistake when pasting the code here, or does the file really have that mistake on your machine, too?  If so, something else going on.

Comment: hi it's my pasting error. my pyd file did get built,  as shown in my screenshots in update2

Comment: OK, then I really can't figure out what's going wrong.  I think you'll need help from a Windows developer who can try out your project file and the steps you're following to build it.  Did you get a chance to try out the cmake-based tutorial?  Maybe that can eliminate any potential sources of errors.  If it works, you can use `cmake -G` to automatically generate a properly configured Visual Studio project, which you can then open and add more files to if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Stuart for your kind help and support all along. I will read the cmake tutorial in more depth though you said CMake is not necessary for me as I have Visual Studio.

Comment: Hi Stuart good news! I managed to solve my problem. I've posted my answer too. Thank you so much for everything ! :D

Comment: Good to hear! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have found answer to my problem:

1. Make sure all steps I described previously in my post are done
2. this is what I missed -` It is important to make sure the file type of "example" is Python Extension Module, as shown in the following screenshot [image: Python Extension Module].
   As shown in screenshots of my Updates, initially the Type of my "example.pyd" file was just "File". I managed to convert it to Python Extension Module by adding "cp35-win_amd64." in the file extension, resulting in file name "examplelib.cp35-win_amd64.pyd", and then remove the same texts that were added.